# Install-PackageProvider is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, powershellget

I'm following [Get Started with the PowerShell Gallery](http://www.powershellgallery.com/GettingStarted) which states that the PowerShellGet module exists in Windows 10 (which I am using - build 14721). To confirm, I am running PowerShell v5:

```
>$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.14271.1000
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14271.1000
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

[Get Started with the PowerShell Gallery](http://www.powershellgallery.com/GettingStarted) states:

> PowerShellGet also requires the NuGet provider to work with the PowerShell Gallery. You will be prompted to install the NuGet provider automatically upon first use of PowerShellGet if the NuGet provider is not in one of the following locations: 
>   •$env:ProgramFiles\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies
>   •$env:LOCALAPPDATA\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies

I don't have anything in those locations:

```
>ls $env:LOCALAPPDATA\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies    
>ls $env:ProgramFiles\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies
ls : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ ls $env:ProgramFiles\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...viderAssemblies:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

[Get Started with the PowerShell Gallery](http://www.powershellgallery.com/GettingStarted) then states:

> Or, you can run Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force to automate the download and installation of the NuGet provider.

If I try that:

```
>Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force
Install-PackageProvider : The term 'Install-PackageProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm very confused. I have PowerShell v5 but it seems I don't have everything that's supposed to be there, namely PowerShellGet.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Are you running the Powershell console as Administrator?  By default I  believe the PS console or ISE is run as a limited user.  Try right clicking Powershell from the Start menu and choose Run as Administrator.

Comment: Just tried running "Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force" as admin, same result :(

Comment: Does your PS Console title say `Administrator:`?  Also, have you checked https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt676543.aspx and tried using `Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable` when I try in PS v5 on Win 7, I get an error indicating ListAvailable is not a recognized param.

Comment: Just rebooting to install an update. Will let you know.

Comment: >Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable

Get-PackageProvider : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ListAvailable'.

Comment: Try without the param, I got that same message.

Comment: >Get-PackageProvider

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
msi                      10.0.10074.0     {AdditionalArguments}
Programs                 10.0.10074.0     {IncludeWindowsInstaller, IncludeSystemComponent}

Comment: I am seeing that the nuget module loads, but does not export any functions at all. So the installer has silently borked for me. I am running 5.1

Answer (score 10):

When I did `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PackageManagement`, as Adam Bertram suggested, I found that there was a different version in my home folder, cruft from a previous install of Windows that got copied across to a new machine:

```
> Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PackageManagement


    Directory: C:\Users\<myusername>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.4.7      PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-Packa...


    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-Packa..
```

Deleting this version, or before that just forcing the system version to be used with `Import-Module PackageManagement -RequiredVersion 1.0.0.1`, allowed me to get the NuGet provider installed.

Answer (score 5):

"Install-PackageProvider" was not introduced until PowerShell 5.1

Answer (score 3):

This error means that PowerShell can't find the module that Install-PackageProvider is a part of.  Install-PackageProvider is a member of the PackageManagement module. To verify this, run Get-Module

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PackageManagement
```

If this errors out, you'll need to ensure you have the PackageManagement folder a  folder inside of your $env:PSModulePath. Here's a quick way to look through each of the folders for the PackageManagement folder.

```
$env:psmodulepath.Split(';') | foreach {gci $_ -filter '*packagemanagement*'}
```

If nothing comes back, you don't even have the PackageManagement module folder anywhere where it can be auto-imported by PowerShell.

If that's the case, I'd recommend to reinstall [PowerShell v5 RTM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395).

Comment: Thanks Adam, have upgraded to Windows 10 build 13279 and am getting the same symptoms. Have visited your link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395) and (not surprisingly) there's no option to download WMF5.0 for Windows 10. Am now utterly stumped.

Comment: oh, and:

>Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable
Get-PackageProvider : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ListAvailable'.

Comment: You'd likely have to  use Add/Remove programs and Features to remove PowerShell or WMF5.0 since it would be an OS bundled component.

Comment: Yeah, that feels a bit dangerous. Think I'm just gonna have to downgrade to latest publicly available Win10, I'm on the fast ring for updates and am willing to bet that's part of the problem.

Comment: Same problem for me. `(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PackageManagement).ExportedCommands` lists only `Find-Package Get-Package Get-PackageProvider Get-PackageSource Install-Package Register-PackageSource Set-PackageSource
 Unregister-PackageSource Uninstall-Package Save-Package`

Comment: you can find 5.1 at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

Answer (score 0):

I had to open up the folder
Directory: C:\Users<myusername>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

and rename/delete the PackageManagement folder
Then everything started working more better.

Answer (score 0):

On my Win2019, Get-PackageProvider (with capital letters) didn't work but get-packageprovider did.
This Powershell that should be "the" solution always surprises me :-/